# Get the HTTP response from the AWS API GATEWAY which is bound to a lambda function link using C++

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, http, aws-api-gateway

I would like to make a function using C++ that enables me to get the HTTP response code given the fact that I already have the Invoke URL generated from the AWS API GATEWAY. So in other words I want to trigger this API linked to a Lambda function in AWS using a C++ function and intercept it's response code
The invoke URL looks like this:

```
https://link-to-execute-api.amazonaws.com/test_env/licence_check
```

This link will be sent as a request along with some query parameters.

Comment: So, your real question is, how to send an HTTP request to any web server and read its response? There are tons of HTTP APIs/libraries available for C++ for that purpose. So, just pick one (asking for recommendations is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here), and follow the instructions in Amazon's API docs for the format of the request/response data. What SPECIFICALLY do you need help with?

Comment: I was thinking about a way to implement the solution but I have found nothing related to C++ and AWS API GATEWAY. But yeah I will look for more resources

Comment: I doubt you will find anything *specific* to C++ and AWS. But web APIs are language-agnostic, so any HTTP/REST example will translate to any C++-based HTTP library. Did you read the [Amazon API Gateway documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) yet? It explains the HTTP, REST, and WebSocket APIs that the Gateway provides.